# Google Cloud Storage gcsfs - read a .tar file directly into python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tar

I have a .tar file in GCS and I want to be able to read the file directly into python, without the intermediary step of downloading the file somewhere first.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
import gcsfs
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')

with fs.open('my_bucket/my_tar_file.tar', 'rb') as f:
    tarfile.open(f)
```

But `f` is an already-open file connection and so of course `.open` again doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tarfile library like what @LaurentLAPORTE did but implemented it in a different way. Open the tar file using object `fs` then use the fileobject for `tarfile.open` and loop through the tarfile members to get the content of the file.

```
import tarfile
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="your-project-here")

with fs.open('your-bucket/test.tar') as f:
    tr = tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:')

    for member in tr.getmembers():
        f=tr.extractfile(member)
        content=f.read()
        print(content.decode('utf-8')) // add decode since output in bytes and not in utf-8 format
    tr.close()
```

test.tar (which is uploaded to my bucket as well) contains sample_file.txt and its contents are:
[image]

Test run:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) function accept a `fileobj` parameter:

> If `fileobj` is specified, it is used as an alternative to a file object opened in binary mode for name. It is supposed to be at position 0.

So, this solution should work:

```py
import contextlib
import tarfile

import gcsfs


fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="my-google-project")

with contextlib.closing(tarfile.open(fileobj=fs, mode='r:')) as f:
    for entry in f:
        ...
```

Don't forget to close your `fs` file.

Comment: Hmm looks like a few problems... `mode=r:` fails with `ValueError: mode must be 'r', 'a', 'w' or 'x'`. Changing to other modes gives `AttributeError: 'GCSFileSystem' object has no attribute 'tell'`. Lastly, not sure if you had in mind a whole directory or specific file - but just to confirm that I want to be able to open a specific file, not every file in `target_dir`

Comment: Well, my first answer was with `tarfile.open`, parameters are not the same than `tarfile.TarFile`. I revert my answer…

Comment: You can use `TarFile.getmember(name)` to get the `TarInfo` object of a specific name.

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think its going to work :( i have the same `AttributeError`